# Why the true email address validate failed for sails.js

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

I use last version of sails.js to programmer my code: 0.11.0
my date module is：

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
firstName: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

lastName: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
email:{
  type:"string",
  required: true,
  email:true,
  unique:true
},
address:{
  type:"string"
},
telephone:{
  type:"string"
},
password:{
  type:"string"
}
}
};
```

my config/blueprint.js is:

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
     action:true,
     rest: true,
     prefix: '/api/v1',
};
```

when I want to request get method a string:

```
 http://localhost:1337/api/v1/user/create?firstName="Michell"&lastName="Loo"&email=take@gmail.com&telephone="0468889799"
```

api/controllers/Usercontroller.js

```
module.exports = {
register: function(req, res){
    res.view();

}

create: function(req, res){
    res.view();
}
};
```

I get the response with an error:

```
{
"error": "E_VALIDATION",
"status": 400,
"summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
"model": "User",
"invalidAttributes": {
"email": [
  {
    "rule": "email",
    "message": "\"email\" validation rule failed for input: 'take@gmail.com'"
  }
 ]
}
```

}

I think the email address is correct and validated for my request case.

I do not know what happens for sails.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your definition to the following:

```
email: {
  type: 'email',
  required: true,
  unique: true
}
```